# What is the difference between to repeat & to recur?

Tags: meaning

As google says,both means to say or to do something again. So how can I distinguish which one and when to use? 
Just tell me the difference okay

Comment: Can you cite the exact Google text stating that 'recur' means 'to say  or to do something again'?

Comment: I suggest Google says nothing at all, but refers you to various dictionaries… which please do quote.

When you can show how at least three different dictionaries explain "repeat" and "recur" and then why that's not clear, that might make a Question.